# Replacing a For Each loop with something faster

Tags: excel, performance, vba

I'm a very inexperienced VBA user, I've just created my first "For Each" loop but it's very slow.  I'm happy that it works but eager to know if there is a alternative method that is quicker.  Any advice would be appreciated but please bear in mind my inexperience!

My routine takes two variables "UserSelectionMin" and "UserSelectionMax" and uses them in conjunction with the RandBetween function to place a value in every cell in the selected range (all the selected cells will be empty).

```
Sub RandomScores()

Dim addr As String
addr = Selection.Address

' opens a userform and collects the min value, assigned to UserSelectionMin (which is declared as an integer)
MinScore
' opens a userform and collects the max value, assigned to UserSelectionMax (which is declared as an integer)
MaxScore

For Each c In Worksheets("matches").Range(addr).Cells
If Abs(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(UserSelectionMin, UserSelectionMax)
Next

Unload RandomScoreFormMin
Unload RandomScoreFormMax

End Sub
```

The MinScore and MaxScore procedures are below although these bits seem to be working OK.

```
Sub MinScore()
With RandomScoreFormMin.ListBoxMin
.AddItem "0"
.AddItem "1"
End With
RandomScoreFormMin.Show vbModal
End Sub

Sub MaxScore()
With RandomScoreFormMax.ListBoxMax
    .AddItem "1"
    .AddItem "2"
    .AddItem "3"
End With
RandomScoreFormMax.Show vbModal
MsgBox "You selected " & UserSelectionMin & " as your min score and " & UserSelectionMax & " as your max score"
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks a lot like you're missing a call to MaxScore before the For Each loop start.

Comment: Thanks Vogel612, I had missed that line out of the post.  Although it does appear in my code.  Have now added the missing line.

Comment: Thanks Mat's Mug - have now added code for MinScore and MaxScore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This smells:

```
' opens a userform and collects the min value, assigned to UserSelectionMin (which is declared as an integer)
MinScore
' opens a userform and collects the max value, assigned to UserSelectionMax (which is declared as an integer)
MaxScore
```

You are using *global variables* - variables should have the tightest possible scope, and be passed to procedures as *parameters*; both `MinScore` and `MaxScore` should be `Function` procedures that *return* a value.

> ```
> Sub MinScore()
> With RandomScoreFormMin.ListBoxMin
> .AddItem "0"
> .AddItem "1"
> End With
> RandomScoreFormMin.Show vbModal
> End Sub
> ```

Indentation is important for readability. It should look something like this:

```
Sub MinScore()
    With RandomScoreFormMin.ListBoxMin
        .AddItem "0"
        .AddItem "1"
    End With
    RandomScoreFormMin.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

However a more pressing issue is the fact that you are working against the form's *default instance* - which is a bad habit to take. Instead, you should create an *object*:

```
Dim view As RandomScoreFormMin
Set view = New RandomScoreFormMin

view.ListBoxMin.AddItem "0"
view.ListBoxMin.AddItem "1"

view.Show vbModal
```

and as I mentioned, that should be a *function*, which returns the user-selected min value:

```
Private Function GetMin() As Integer
    Dim view As RandomScoreFormMin
    Set view = New RandomScoreFormMin

    view.ListBoxMin.AddItem "0"
    view.ListBoxMin.AddItem "1"

    view.Show vbModal

    GetMin = view.ListBoxMin.Value
End Function
```

Now you no longer need to worry about loading/unloading the form, since a new instance is used every time this function is called. And then the calling code can use a local variable instead of a global:

```
Dim minValue As Integer
minValue = GetMin
```

---

Regarding the performance of the `ForEach` loop:

```
For Each c In Worksheets("matches").Range(addr).Cells
    If Abs(c.Value) = 0 Then 
        c.Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(UserSelectionMin, UserSelectionMax)
    End If
Next
```

Taking the absolute value of the cell's content looks like a little hack - that would deserve a little comment to explain *why* it's done, otherwise a maintainer might deem it redundant, and remove it.

My guts are telling me that it's a way of getting an `Integer` value from the cell, even if the cell is empty. In that case, `CInt(c.Value)` would do a better job.

Another thing is that you are updating a worksheet in a tight loop; Excel is redrawing itself and recalculating the affected cells every time a value is written!

You can turn off screen updating and automatic calculation, while you're updating the sheet's contents:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Just don't forget to set `ScreenUpdating` back to True and calculation back to automatic after the loop completes (ideally in an error handler, so that if a runtime error occurs, screen updating is turned back on), so that Excel doesn't appear to remain "frozen"!

---

You have a potential bug here:

> ```
> Dim addr As String
> addr = Selection.Address
> ```

You're using the *currently selected range's address*...

> ```
> For Each c In Worksheets("matches").Range(addr).Cells
> ```

...and then you're *assuming* that this range is on the `"matches"` worksheet - and it *may* not be all the time. If you mean to work with `Selection`, know that it *is* a `Range`, so you could do this instead:

```
For Each c In Selection.Cells
```

Otherwise, you need to validate the `Selection` before you use it - is it on the worksheet you're expecting?

---

Using `WorksheetFunction` is inherently slow, and should be avoided as much as possible; if your goal is to return a random number between X and Y, you could use VBA's random number generator instead of a worksheet function - here's a little formula to get a random integer between `lowerbound` and `upperbound`:

> ```
> Int ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
> ```

`Rnd` returns a number that's smaller than 1, and greater than or equal to 0. It should be used in conjunction with the `Randomize` keyword:

```
Randomize
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    c.Value = Int((UserSelectionMax - UserSelectionMin + 1) * Rnd + UserSelectionMin
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Mat's Mug, that's incredibly helpful.  I guess it might be a bit tiresome dealing with errors and anomalies from inexperienced users - I really appreciate your patience.

I started at the bottom and used Rnd instead of RandBetween, then turned off the screenupdating, then turned off the autocalculation.  Tested the code each time and it was the autocalculation that was slowing everything down.  With that turned off, I can do 200 lines in about half a second - that's down from about 5 minutes so an enormous improvement.  Now I'll work through your other suggestions. Thanks once again!

Comment: That's what Code Review is for! Come back anytime with more working code! ;)

Comment: @MarkShepherd as a side note, I'm working with another fellow VBA reviewer here, on a little project that might interest you - get the latest release of [Rubberduck](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/releases), a COM add-in for the VBA Editor, that can find code issues and help you refactor your VBA code (and lots, lots more) - we need people like you to find and report bugs in our little ducky! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little unclear on the nature of some of the cells' values, i.e. whether they are typed values or cells containing formulas that may return either *""* or *0*. The `Abs(c.Value)` seems to indicate that you are looking to determine whether converted underlying values are equal to zero. This should get you started on a block processing routine that replaces the loop.

```
With Worksheets("matches").Range(addr).Cells
    .Replace What:=0, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(" & UserSelectionMin & Chr(44) & UserSelectionMax & Chr(41)
        .Cells = .Value
    End With
End With
```

The worksheet formula is necessary as code like `(Rnd * UserSelectionMax) + UserSelectionMin` used on a block will not produce a random number for each cell; just one random number distributed to all of the cells.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.  All the cells in the selected range will be empty.  Perhaps `Abs(c.Value)=0` is incorrect?  It did seem odd to me but worked so I left it alone!

Comment: @MarkShepherd - Strictly speaking, zero is neither positive or negative so `Abs(0)` does nothing and neither -1 or 1 are equal to zero with or without the `Abs(...)`. In short, it seems redundant.

Comment: @MarkShepherd - If the cells to be considered will be blank and you are not trying to put a random number in a cell containing 0, then the `.Replace(...)` code line can be removed.